# pandas data in cell start with quotes but not ending causes Error tokenizing data. C error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV file that I'm opening as part of an automation and I came across this error in one of the files `Error tokenizing data. C error`

After exploring a bit I noticed that in one cell I have a quotation mark that doesn't end and it's the problem. Any idea on how I can fix it without ignoring the line?

my python line:
`pd.read_csv(file_path, delimiter='\t', index_col=False)`

good cell: `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; CRO-L03) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.105 Mobile Safari/537.36`

bad cell `"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.38 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/66.6 Mobile/14A5297c Safari/602.1`

example for the error with dia.quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE:
input:

```
app_id_dummy    alert_type  timestamp   session_id
test    active  1618870097991   63f3eded98
test    active  1618869937038   ea86303028
test    active  1618869423974   55e809427a
```

output:

```
ParserWarning: Conflicting values for 'quoting': '0' was provided, but the dialect specifies '3'. Using the dialect-specified value.
  parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
```

I want to specify that it still works but I'm afraid it could cause a problem when I'll give it a different csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dialect` option can be used in read_csv() method to read the csv with single quote, without ignoring the line.

**Example:**

```
from io import StringIO
import csv
data = """label1,label2,label3
index1,"a,c,e
index2,b,d,f"""

dia = csv.excel()
dia.quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE
pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), dialect=dia) ## replace StringIO(data) with your csv file, and add dia.delimiter='\t' as per csv data
```

**Output**

```
    label1  label2  label3
index1  "a  c   e
index2  b   d   f
```

label1 - index1 consists of "a" with a single quote.

**Explanation**

The dialect keyword gives greater flexibility in specifying the file format. By default it uses the Excel dialect but you can specify either the dialect name or a csv.Dialect instance.
As we have the data with unenclosed quotes:
By default, read_csv uses the Excel dialect and treats the double quote as the quote character, which causes it to fail when it finds a newline before it finds the closing double quote.

Comment: Works! all but to add to your answer I also need to write this line: `dia.delimiter = '\t'`

Comment: is there any way for it to choose its own dialect? because sometimes i get 'quoting': '0' was provided, but the dialect specifies '3'

Comment: Can you please share an input and output example.

Comment: I added one in my question